# I have to modify a Polynomial implemented with integers, so that it can hold BigIntegers as well

Tags: java, int, biginteger

I have to modify a Polynomial implemented with integers, so that it can hold BigIntegers as well. I'm getting null pointer exception error. Please help!

Exception at Graph.Polynomial.plus(Polynomial.java:59) and at Graph.Polynomial.main(Polynomial.java:189)

```
package Graph;
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Polynomial {
private BigInteger[] coef;  // coefficients
private int deg;     // degree of polynomial (0 for the zero polynomial) 

/** Creates the constant polynomial P(x) = 1.
  */
public Polynomial(){
    coef = new BigInteger[1];
    coef[0] = new BigInteger("1");
    deg = 0;
}



/** Creates the linear polynomial of the form P(x) =  x + a.
  */
public Polynomial(BigInteger a){
    coef = new BigInteger[2];
    coef[1] = new BigInteger("1");
    coef[0] = a;
    deg = 1;
}




/** Creates the polynomial P(x) = a * x^b.
  */
public Polynomial(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
     coef =  new BigInteger[b.intValue()+1];
     coef[b.intValue()] = a; 
    deg = degree();
}





/** Return the degree of this polynomial (0 for the constant polynomial).
  */
public int degree() {
    int d = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < coef.length; i++)
        if (coef[i]!= new BigInteger("0")) d = i;
    return d;
}





/** Return the sum of this polynomial and b, i.e., return c = this + b.
  */
public Polynomial plus(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(new BigInteger(("0"), Math.max(a.deg, b.deg)));
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(a.coef[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(b.coef[i]);
    
    c.deg = c.degree();
    return c;
}




/** Return the difference of this polynomial and b, i.e., return (this - b).
  */
public Polynomial minus(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0", Math.max(a.deg, b.deg)));
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].add(a.coef[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= b.deg; i++) c.coef[i] = c.coef[i].subtract(b.coef[i]);
    
    c.deg = c.degree();
    return c;
}






/** Return the product of this polynomial and b, i.e., return (this * b).
  */
public Polynomial times(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("a.deg").add(new BigInteger("b.deg")));
    for (int i = 0; i <= a.deg; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j <= b.deg; j++)
            c.coef[i+j] = c.coef[i+j].add((a.coef[i].multiply(b.coef[j])));
    c.deg = c.degree();
    return c;
}






/** Return the composite of this polynomial and b, i.e., return this(b(x))  - compute using Horner's method.
  */
public Polynomial compose(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;
    Polynomial c = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("0"));
    for (int i = a.deg; i >= 0; i--) {
        Polynomial term = new Polynomial(a.coef[i], new BigInteger("0"));
        c = term.plus(b.times(c));
    }
    return c;
}




/** Return true whenever this polynomial and b are identical to one another.
  */
public boolean equals(Polynomial b) {
    Polynomial a = this;
    if (a.deg != b.deg) return false;
    for (int i = a.deg; i >= 0; i--)
        if (a.coef[i] != b.coef[i]) return false;
    return true;
}





/** Evaluate this polynomial at x, i.e., return this(x).
  */
public BigInteger evaluate(BigInteger x) {
    BigInteger p = new BigInteger("0");
    for (int i = deg; i >= 0; i--)
        p = coef[i].add((new BigInteger("x").multiply(new BigInteger("p"))));
    return p;
}






/** Return the derivative of this polynomial.
  */
public Polynomial differentiate() {
    if (deg == 0) return new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("0"));
    Polynomial deriv = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("deg").subtract(new BigInteger("1")));
    deriv.deg = deg - 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < deg; i++)
        deriv.coef[i] = new BigInteger("i + 1").multiply(coef[i + 1]);
    return deriv;
}





/** Return a textual representation of this polynomial.
  */
public String toString() {
    if (deg ==  0) return "" + coef[0];
    if (deg ==  1) return coef[1] + "x + " + coef[0];
    String s = coef[deg] + "x^" + deg;
    for (int i = deg-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if      (coef[i] == new BigInteger("0")) continue;
        else if (coef[i].signum()==1) s = s + " + " + ( coef[i]);
        else if (coef[i].signum()== -1) s = s + " - " + (coef[i].multiply(new BigInteger("-1")));
        if      (i == 1) s = s + "x";
        else if (i >  1) s = s + "x^" + i;
    }
    return s;
}






public static void main(String[] args) {
    Polynomial zero = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("0"), new BigInteger("0"));

    Polynomial p1   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("476867"), new BigInteger("8"));
    Polynomial p2   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("3"), new BigInteger("2"));
    Polynomial p3   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("-1"), new BigInteger("0"));
    Polynomial p4   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("-2"), new BigInteger("1"));
    Polynomial p    = p1.plus(p2).plus(p3).plus(p4);

    Polynomial q1   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("3"), new BigInteger("2"));
    Polynomial q2   = new Polynomial(new BigInteger("5"), new BigInteger("0"));
    Polynomial q    = q1.minus(q2);


    Polynomial r    = p.plus(q);
    Polynomial s    = p.times(q);
    Polynomial t    = p.compose(q);

    System.out.println("zero(x) =     " + zero);
    System.out.println("p(x) =        " + p);
    System.out.println("q(x) =        " + q);
    System.out.println("p(x) + q(x) = " + r);
    System.out.println("p(x) * q(x) = " + s);
    System.out.println("p(q(x))     = " + t);
    System.out.println("0 - p(x)    = " + zero.minus(p));
    System.out.println("p(3)        = " + p.evaluate(new BigInteger("3")));
    System.out.println("p'(x)       = " + p.differentiate());
    System.out.println("p''(x)      = " + p.differentiate().differentiate());


    Polynomial poly = new Polynomial();

    for(int k=0; k<=3; k++){
        poly = poly.times(new Polynomial(new BigInteger("-k")));
    }

    System.out.println(poly);
   }

   }
```

Comment: Which is line 59?  What exception do you get?

Comment: So similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597081/how-can-i-fix-this-plus-method-in-polynomial-class-using-biginteger

Comment: @PopoFibo: seriously -- it's a direct copy of that question. Voting to close this. Come on original poster, please don't do this sort of thing. At least don't change sign on names or have sock puppet accounts.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I wonder if perhaps the two are classmates with the same homework assignment...

Comment: @Azar: same exact comments? same exact formatting? The odds are low.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a polynomial with this constructor:

```
public Polynomial(BigInteger a, BigInteger b) {
     coef =  new BigInteger[b.intValue()+1];
     coef[b.intValue()] = a; 
     deg = degree();
}
```

most of the entries in the `coef` array will be `null`. This leads to a NPE when you later add two such polynomials with `plus`

Answer (score 1):

On line 58 you have

`Polynomial c = new Polynomial(new BigInteger(("0"), Math.max(a.deg, b.deg)));`

I think you have a bug here.
This seems to create polynomial c of degree 0.

Basically you're calling this constructor.

`BigInteger(String val, int radix)`

I don't think this was your intention here,
maybe you put some brackets at some wrong places.